# Error in returning Generic Record in spring cloud stream

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying a transformer in spring cloud stream to consume a json and generate an avro schema record. Can you give me an idea as to what is the right way to right this?
After following all the documentation I wrote the following transformer

```
  @Bean
  public Function<String, GenericRecord> transformMaestroDirectSearchRequest() {
    return value -> {
      try {
        GenericRecord genericRecord = TransformJsonToAvro.convertJsonToAvro(
            value, transformJsonToAvro.getMaestroDirectSearchSchema());
        return genericRecord;
      } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
```

But I keep getting this error when I run the integration test

```
 nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Not an enum:
```

```
  @Test
  public void maestroSearchRequestTransformTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    GenericMessage<byte[]> inputMessage =
        new GenericMessage<>(Utils.getJsonFile("Maestro_direct_Req.json").getBytes());

    this.input.send(inputMessage);
    Message<byte[]> receive = this.output.receive();
    System.out.println(receive.getPayload());
  }
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

I have already verified that the conversion logic for creating the GenericRecord works well, and there is nothing wrong there (i.e. a valid GenericRecord Object is generated)

Here is the full stack trace

```
2020-11-18 13:36:31.112 ERROR 89354 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@16fc5622]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Not an enum: {"type":"record","default":"null"}]}],"default":"null"}]} (through reference chain: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record["schema"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema["enumSymbols"])
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertToInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:289)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.convertToInternal(ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.NegotiatingMessageConverterWrapper.toMessage(NegotiatingMessageConverterWrapper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.NegotiatingMessageConverterWrapper.toMessage(NegotiatingMessageConverterWrapper.java:139)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.toMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertValueToMessage(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:705)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertOutputValueIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:667)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:600)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:443)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:431)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:609)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:387)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:375)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:156)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:637)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.fallbackToInvokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:630)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInvokeExceptionAndFallbackToExpressionIfAny(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:614)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:585)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Not an enum: {"type":"record",..... removed real json ,"default":"null"}]}],"default":"null"}]} (through reference chain: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record["schema"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema["enumSymbols"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:763)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertToInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:271)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not an enum: {"type":"record",... removed real json...."default":"null"}]}],"default":"null"}]}
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.getEnumSymbols(Schema.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    ... 133 more
```

Comment: Show the complete stack trace; truncating the caused  by trace makes it useless.

Comment: @GaryRussell - added the entire stack trace. I removed the real json values, as that would have made this too long.